# PHP use parent class functions

Tags: php, mysql

I have Afactory mysql simple class and I can use with this method:

`Afactory.class.php`:

```
require_once ( substr( dirname(__FILE__), 0, -5 ).'config.inc' );
class AFactory
{
    private $DBhost;
    private $DBuser;
    private $DBpass;
    private $DBname;
    private $DBport;
    private $queryResult;
    private $linkConnection;
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->DBhost=LOCALHOST;
        $this->DBuser=USERNAME;
        $this->DBpass=PASSWORD;
        $this->DBname=DATABASE;
    }
    public function getDBO()
    {
        $linkConnection = mysql_connect ($this->DBhost , $this->DBuser , $this->DBpass);
        mysql_query("set charset set utf8", $linkConnection);
        mysql_query("set names 'utf8'", $linkConnection);           
        return  mysql_select_db($this->DBname) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }
    public function setQuery($query)
    {
        return mysql_query($query);
    }
    public function loadAssoc()
    {
        $array=NULL;
        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->queryResult ))
             $array[] = $result;
        return $array;      
    }
}
```

with this file i can use class and class's functions

**text.php:**

```
$db=new AFactory();
$link=$db->getDBO();
$db->loadAssoc($db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM users")); // this can return array
```

i want to create new class and use Afactory class

**testclass.php:**

```
include ( substr( dirname(__FILE__), 0, -5 ).'alachiq_settings.php' );
class alachiq extends AFactory{
    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
    } 
    public function fetchArray(){
       echo parent::getDBO(); //this line can return successfull connect to db
       return parent::loadAssoc(parrent::setQuery("SELECT * FROM users")); //fetch sql command

    }
}
```

after create alachiq class with Afactory extended i cant use this method:

**useTestClass:**

```
include('testclass.php');
print_r(  alachiq::fetchArray() );
```

What's my code problem?

Comment: A tentative question: why use an abstract factory pattern for database connections? Do you connect to a lot of databases simultaneously? Not criticizing (yet :P ), just curious.

Answer (score 7):

First a short note on mysql:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

---

Turn on your error_reporting / display_errors...

It's only a typo here (`parrent` instead of `parent`):

```
return parent::loadAssoc(parrent::setQuery("SELECT * FROM settings")); //fetch sql command
// -------------------------^
```

*correct*:

```
return parent::loadAssoc(parent::setQuery("SELECT * FROM settings")); //fetch sql command
```

---

Also, you cannot call non-static functions in a static context:

```
print_r(  alachiq::fetchArray() );
```

This was a static call; use a class instance:

```
$instance = new alachiq();
print_r(  $instance->fetchArray() );
```

Comment: @mahdipishguy because you anywhere set `$this->queryResult`? You maybe want to set it in setQuery method instead of returning?

Comment: @mahdipishguy or because you don't accept a parameter in loadAssoc method, but use the not set property...

Comment: @mahdipishguy If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you have here is a confusion of how to use static and object methods.

You are calling it like this:

```
print_r(alachiq::fetchArray());
```

That implies that you want to call it as a static method. The `fetchArray` method isn't declared as `static`, but you can get away with that if the method you're calling acts as a static method.

The problem, however comes when `fetchArray` calls `parent::getDBO`. `getDBO` makes reference to `$this`, which means that the method is **not** `static`.

This is why calling `alachiq::fetchArray()` fails; you're trying to make a static call on a non static method.

**The solution:**

You need to create an instance of the object and call that:

```
$myobj = new alachiq();
print_r($myobj->fetchArray());
```

That should help.